# Firebase unit test error - Cannot parse Firebase url

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, firebase, angular

Firebase unit test error - Cannot parse Firebase url.

I'm trying to get the test to run correctly.
My test code seems fine but it doesn't like the Firebase usage in the code.

**Here is my code I'm testing:**

```
 export class FirebaseService {
   refUsers: Firebase;

   constructor() {
     this.refUsers = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com/users");
   }

   public addUser(newUser: Object): void{    
     this.refUsers.push(newUser, ()=>{     
     });
   }
 }
```

**Here is my unit test:**

```
 import { FirebaseService } from '../app/firebase-service';

 describe('FirebaseService', () => {

     it('saves an item to Firebase', () => {
         var refUsers = new Firebase('');
         var service = new FirebaseService();

         spyOn(service.refUsers, 'push');
         service.addUser({ item: true });

         expect(service.refUsers.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
     })

 });
```

**This is the error message:**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this wasnt working was 2 things.

1. I wasnt building the tests before running them
2. var refUsers = new Firebase(''); should of had the name of the Fire url instead of ''

Comment: Since you are testing the class `FirebaseService` and not the `Firebase` class, I would mock the `Firebase` class completely.

Comment: How do you mock the firebase class?

Comment: Thanks! Looks nicer for tests

Comment: Eric Martinez - Do you know how to import the mockfirebase for unit test instead of require?

Comment: No, sorry, I have no idea, I've never used Firebase before. I just googled.